# Dealing with large amounts of obersvations for stock returns in a given dataset while maintaining correlation

Tags: r, stock

This is more of general question:

I'm currently looking for any guidlines how to deal with too many observations of daily stock returns in a given dataset. I already removed outlieres but I still have way to much observations. I'm using R.

I want to drasticly compromize the number of observations for my further research without ruin the correlation in my dataset, but I'm not sure how to.

Any suggestions are welcome

Best regards

Comment: Yes, this is a general question. Probably too general. The best you can do here is probably to sample your data frame. `df2 <-  df[sample(nrow(df), 1000),]` would get you 1000 rows of your data. If the sample is large enough, the correlations should be similar.

Comment: Hey Allan, thanks for the answer,

Comment: you can also use sample_n() from tidyverse

Comment: Thanks :) I hoped there is more general guideline. I want to determine an Minimum Spanning Tree for the S&P500 but there are to many observations